# Regex: Find space before and after hyphenated words

Tags: regex, find, hyphenation

How can I find the space before and after hyphenated words?
i.e. "This is my hyphenated-word example test"

I need the space between: "my hyphenated-word" and "hyphenated-word example"

Comment: Are you ready to sacrifice words like _Ctrl-Alt-Del_ or _politico-military_? I mean, do you consider hyphenated all words that have at least one hyphen in them, with no other conditions?

Comment: why - do you want to just select the hyphenated-word? if not, what language - does is support look ahead / look behind?

Comment: What do you want to do, and why?  Why don’t you just match `(\s*)(your-word-here)(\s*)`, and then look at whether groups 1 and 3 have positive length? No lookarounds required.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [lookahead and lookbehind](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html).

The space before:

```
\s(?=([^\s]+-[^\s]+))
```

The space after:

```
 (?<=([^\s]+-[^\s]+))\s
```

Comment: +1 But it will only work in .net, because all others do not support infinite length lookbehind.

Comment: @stema You are right, .NET's is the "regexp flavor" that I've been using lately. I am not sure if Javascript or Java provide similar capabilities - I've been out of these for several years, but I guess not.

Comment: see http://www.regular-expressions.info/javascript.html if you want to know that javascript does not support lookbehind...

Answer (score 1):

in case you just want to **get the hyphenated-word itself**, retrieve the whole match (e.g. capturing group 0) with this regex:

```
\w+(?:-\w+)+
```